# Attribute set in portlet session is not available in servlet session

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, portlet

Post on Liferay Forums: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/47412302

I have a simple application setup within a JSR-286 portlet to retrieve the value from a `Portlet`  `session.attribute`

doView() method:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
     throws PortletException, IOException
   {
     renderResponse.setContentType("text/html");
     getFormBean(renderRequest.getPortletSession());
     PortletURL renderUrl = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
     renderUrl.setWindowState(WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
     PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(this.viewUrl);
     dispatcher.include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
   }
```

I set my attribute here in
TestPortlet.java:

```
private void getFormBean(PortletSession session)
{
    String testVar = (String)session.getAttribute("testAttr", 1);
    if (null == testVar) {
        System.out.println("Setting Attribute inside Portlet");
        session.setAttribute("testAttr", "TESTING SESSION", 1);
    }
}
```

And retrieve the attribute here in TestServlet.java (same package):

```
private void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
         String testVal = (String) request.getSession(true).getAttribute("testAttr");
         System.out.println("Test Attribute from Servlet:"+testVal);
}
```

The output of the application returns null

```
Setting Attribute in Portlet
Test Attribute from Servlet:null
```

Output should be:

```
Test Attribute from Servlet:TESTING SESSION
```

This application ***does work*** on my local setup, however not on a remote server with almost the same configurations.
I've included the javax-servlet-api-3.1.0 in my tomcat/lib to retrieve the `HttpServletRequest` Class, haven't found what else could be missing. I also haven't seen any Exceptions/ClassNotFound Errors.

Could there be any kind of server configuration that could interfere with the Session? (Authentication, network config, security)

Local setup

- Tomcat 7.0.33
- jdk-1.7 (compiled with 1.6 and 1.7)

Remote setup

- Tomcat 7.0.33
- Apache Web Server
- jdk-1.6.0u35
- more jar files in /lib (jdbc drivers, etc)

Comment: What is the result when you test it with PortletSession Scope? String testVar = (String)session.getAttribute("testAttr", 2);

Comment: Are you asking me to test retrieving the session attribute value from within it's own declaration? confused

Comment: Sorry i misunderstand the first part, in TestPortler.java you set it with session.setAttribute("testAttr", "TESTING SESSION", 1); did you try it with session.setAttribute("testAttr", "TESTING SESSION", 2);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share session data between portlet and servlet in the same application (war), you have to place the attribute in the application scope, like this:

```
portletSession.setAttribute("testAttr", "TESTING SESSION", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

and then also retrieve it in portlet using scope:

```
portletSession.getAttribute("testAttr", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Comment: Thanks Gas, this does work on my local setup as does the way it was initially defined; however it is still returning null on a remote development server. The major difference between the two being the remote server has more libraries in it's /lib folder and its configured to work with an http server.

Comment: included more info in description

Comment: @ClayBanks then maybe it is Apache<->Tomcat setup problem. Test using simple servlet/jsp if the sessions are working at all, or try to call that remote server bypassing http server.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing - bypassing the http server however still returns null unfortunately

Comment: @ClayBanks is the application configured the same on remote server? Maybe portlet and servlet are in 2 different wars?

Comment: Same exact application on local and remote @Gas

Comment: @ClayBanks so you can only start adding same jars to your local and see when it will stop working, I don't have any other bright ideas ;)