# How to access servlet session attributes within a JSF bean inside a Liferay portlet request?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, liferay, portlet

Is it possible to write just a single attribute to the original session **without using `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>`** with Liferay 6.2.10 and Liferay-Faces-Bridge 3.2.4?

- In a JSF-bean / portlet we configure a export file that must be downloadable via a servlet (inside the same WAR).
- We want to share one specific Object via the session to get used by some JSTL-magic inside the portal.

I have found no other way than setting `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>`, but that pollutes the session with lots of JSF-specific and even more portlet-specific objects that no one needs in the user-global session. As most portlets in that war need to communicate I would either have to switch all to public session attributes or use IPC.

I tried several ways that only yield positive results while not using private session attributes.

```
ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext().getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("SERVICE_CONTEXT", true);

ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
// Does not matter which way
// PortletSession portletSession = (PortletSession)externalContext.getSession(false);
PortletSession portletSession = ((PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest()).getPortletSession();
portletSession.setAttribute("PORTLET_SESSION_PORTLET_SCOPE", true, PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);
portletSession.setAttribute("PORTLET_SESSION_APPLICATION_SCOPE", true, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest((PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest());
httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("EXTERNAL_CONTEXT_SERVLET_REQUEST_SESSION", true);

HttpServletRequest outerRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(httpServletRequest);
outerRequest.getSession().setAttribute("EXTERNAL_CONTEXT_SERVLETS_SERVLET_REQUEST", true);
```

Other options that I would like to avoid would be:

- use a `javax.servlet.Filter` with a `ThreadLocal`
- save the generated document (or export configuration) to a database
- transport the configuration via the client by re-posting it to the export servlet.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27808844/510711) suggests to use the portletSession with ApplicationScoped variables, but I couldn't get the PortletSession.

With setting `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` I get the following attributes set in the original session:

- TEST_WITH_EXTERNAL_CONTEXT_SERVLET_REQUEST_SESSION
- TEST_WITH_PORTLET_SESSION_APPLICATION_SCOPE
- TEST_WITH_SERVICE_CONTEXT
- war_app_name_whatever?TEST_WITH_PORTLET_SESSION_PORTLET_SCOPE

and a great number of other objects (>50) visible in the *global* users session.

Has anyone a good idea how to set just one session attribute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unwrapping the request until reaching a class that does not extend `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` solves the problem.

The request is kindly stored by Liferay and available via  `ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext().getRequest()`.

Liferays `PortalUtil` just unwraps if the request wrapper is in a package that starts with `"com.liferay."` and therefore does not work if a custom request wrapper is used.

```
public static <Type, ValueType extends Type> void setOnOriginalSession(Class<Type> type, ValueType value) {

    HttpServletRequest request = ServiceContextThreadLocal.getServiceContext().getRequest();
    HttpServletRequest originalRequest = unwrapOriginalRequest(request);
    HttpSession originalSession = originalRequest.getSession();

    String attributeNameForType = getAttributeNameForType(type);
    originalSession.setAttribute(attributeNameForType, value);
}

private static HttpServletRequest unwrapOriginalRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    while (request instanceof HttpServletRequestWrapper) {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper httpServletRequestWrapper = (HttpServletRequestWrapper) request;
        request = (HttpServletRequest) httpServletRequestWrapper.getRequest();
    }
    return request;
}
```

Comment: This method will likely not work in Liferay 7.0+ since you won't have direct access to the app server's `HttpServletRequest` anymore. If you are trying to share data between portlets, you should try one of the methods from my blog: https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/how-can-i-share-session-data-across-portlets-in-liferay-.

If you are trying to share data between a servlet application and a portlet, you should probably use an external data source like a database or REST API for both the servlet and portlet.